# i am having problem installing some react dependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

I am new to installing some dependencies in react. I am having problem installing **'npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab @react-google-maps/api axios google-map-react'**. It kept saying **'unable to resolve dependency tree'**

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Delete `package-lock.json`
2. Run `npm install --save --force --legacy-peer`
3. Run `npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab @react-google-maps/api axios google-map-react --save --force --legacy-peer-deps`.

Answer (score -1):

D:\traveltype\eruno>
D:\traveltype\eruno>npm config set legacy-peer-deps true

D:\traveltype\eruno>npm install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).